# Extract all docstrings (__doc__) from my Django files

Tags: python, django, documentation, docstring

I have a project in Django and I write docstrings in my modules, classes and functions. But I need a way to extract all `__doc__` from there automatically. Like "python manage.py collectstatic" but for `.__doc__` instances for all `.py` codes. Something like that? Some ideas?

Comment: You're probably looking for [pydoc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pydoc.html)

Comment: if you are looking for pydoc(and it sounds like you are.) I would recommend investing the extra effort to get sphinx working ... you will not regret it

Answer (score 1):

Giving you a glimpse of  [`pydoc`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pydoc.html)

Example module:

```
# foo.py

def bar():
  """this is the docstring for bar()"""
  print 'hello'


def baz():
  """this is the docstring for baz()"""
  print 'world'
```

Now you can print the docstrings using below command:

```
$ pydoc foo.py
Help on module foo:

NAME
    foo

FILE
    /path/to/foo.py

FUNCTIONS
    bar()
        this is the docstring for bar()

    baz()
        this is the docstring for baz()
```

You can also generate an HTML help file:

```
$ pydoc -w ./foo.py
wrote foo.html
```

which looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Yes, pydoc is util. But in Python 3 not so much. The imports, for example, have conflicts with the pydoc. The text encoding too.